# Angular 2, component inside main component

Tags: angular

I've played with the angular 2 demo on angular.io.
Now I want to create a new component and use it inside my app.

My current app:

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {UsersComponent} from './components/users/component.js';

// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
  url:"app.html"
})
// Component controller
class MyAppComponent {
  newName:string;
  names:Array<string>;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Florian';
  }

  showAlert(){
    alert("It works");
  }

  addName(){
    names.push(newName);
    newName = "";
  }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

My component:

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
// Annotation section
@Component({
  selector: 'users'
})
@Template({
  url:"./template.html"
})
// Component controller
class UsersComponent {
  newName:string;
  names:Array<string>;
  constructor() {

  }

  addName(){
    names.push(newName);
    newName = "";
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the syntax of my user component is correct at all.

My app template:

```
<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
<h2>{{2+2}}</h2>
<hr />
<button (click)="showAlert()">Click to alert</button>
<users></users>
```

So how do I wire up the User component?

The error I get in the console:

```
 "Error loading "components/users/component.js" at <unknown>↵Error loading "components/users/component.js" from "app" at http://localhost:8080/app.es6↵Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Angular calendar demo has two nested components (calendar and calendar-cell)    https://github.com/djsmith42/angular2_calendar.git . From what I can see there your MyAppComponent should reference Users component from @Template's directives list, like this:

```js
@Template({
  url: System.baseURL+'app/components/calendar/calendar.html',
  directives: [
    Foreach,
    If,
    CalendarCell
  ]
})
```

Comment: You were right, thanks for the example. My app did indeed not have the directives array. My template url of my Users component was wrong (should be an absolute path). And I didn't add my component folder to my System.paths in the html file.

Comment: Minor nit: I think you need a 'const' before the directives list. Here is a micro write up with a modified quickstart tutorial: http://bq9.blogspot.ch/2015/03/angular2-dart-nested-components.html

Comment: @buraq nope, that is for dart. This person is using js.

Comment: 'Foreach, If, CalendarCell' all hard references to concrete ng classes. What if they are in separate files? You'll need DI, in that case how would you reference it?

Answer (score 10):

In this link of `Angular2` web https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html# you can see that adding `directives: [...]` inside of `@Components` for example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [UsersComponent]
})
```

but otherwise the link use template inside the component, do not know if this will work if you use `@Template({ url:"app.html"})` outside component.

you can watch the file name `app.appcomponet.ts` for more details, hopefully help.

Comment: ever since RC6, this isn't possible anymore.